# Ignore field for update in spring-r2dbc

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am using spring r2dbc and ReactiveCrudRepository, I have a field which I need to ignore for when update query is generated

```
@Data
@Table(PRODUCT_TABLE)
public class ProductEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // Id generated by database
    private Integer id;

    private Integer companyId;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable = false)
    private String companyName;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    private VerificationStatus verificationStatus;
}
```

How can I ignore companyName in update query. I am able ignore it in insert query using @column but its not working for update

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep the field for update and insert, then mark the field with `@Transient`.

For example,

```
@Transient
private String companyName;
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Transient.html

Comment: But I do want to it use for select statements, it would be ignored in case of Transient

Answer (score 1):

Simplify use

```
@ReadOnlyProperty
```

For example,

```
@ReadOnlyProperty
private String companyName;
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/ReadOnlyProperty.html

Comment: this one will not allow insert field data to persist